# Unity does not show collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider, mesh-collider

Unity does not show collider, i can only see it if i press the edit collider button.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

**Note:** 
Start the Gizmos Button Given in Image.

Answer (score 7):

My suspect is that Gizmos are turned off. Try under `Edit > Project Settings > Physics 2D > Gizmos > Always Show Colliders`.

Comment: On the top/right ish of your scene view, there is a Gizmos button, click on it

Answer (score 0):

Unity shows collider only for objects that was selected in hierarchy. Are you sure you selected one?

Comment: Yes, I am. You can see it on my screenshots.